# What architectural pattern to use in Python desktop application

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am new at Python programming language.
I intend to build desktop applications using "PyQt"...

I have been searching a lot about the best architectural design to use when building my applications.

Each application will be formed of: user interface and a database (mySql).

I appreciate any help in this domain, and some insightful example will be very helpful.

### Edit:

I tried to apply the mvc pattern in a test object as I was advised by my director... This is my code:

The view class (which was generated by the pyuic5 command):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from datetime import *
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 200)

        self.vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.vLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")


        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 20, 366, 206))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(0, 50)
        self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(1, 50)
        self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(2, 50)
        self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(3, 20)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setEnabled(False)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 3)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 1, 1, 3)

        #Add PushButtons
        self.pbNext = QtWidgets.QPushButton(">", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbNext, 3, 2)

        self.pbPrevious = QtWidgets.QPushButton("<", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbPrevious, 3, 1)

        self.pbFirst = QtWidgets.QPushButton("<<", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbFirst, 3, 0)

        self.pbLast = QtWidgets.QPushButton(">>", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbLast, 3, 3)

        self.pbAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbAdd, 0, 4)

        self.pbDelete = QtWidgets.QPushButton("x", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbDelete, 1, 4)

        self.pbOpenId = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OpenId", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbOpenId, 2, 4)

        self.pbQuit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Quit", self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbQuit, 3, 4)

        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Test my dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Id"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "First name"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Last name"))
```

the Model class:

```
from PyQt5 import QtSql, QtCore


class DBModel(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, p_sdbName, p_sHostName, p_sUserName, p_sUserPassword, p_sMainTblName):

        super().__init__()
        # connect to mydb on mysql drive
        bConnected, self.connection = self.connectDB(p_sdbName, p_sHostName, p_sUserName)

        if bConnected:
            self.initModel(p_sMainTblName)
            self.modelRowCount = self.getModelRowCount()
        else:
            self.lastError = "Failed to connect to the database due to the following error: \n{}" \
            .format(self.connection.lastError())

    def connectDB(self, p_dbName, p_hostName, p_userName):

        bReturn = False

        connection = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
        connection.setDatabaseName(p_dbName)
        connection.setHostName(p_hostName)
        connection.setUserName(p_userName)

        if connection.open():
            bReturn = True

        return bReturn, connection

    def initModel(self, p_sTblName):
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self, self.connection)
        self.model.setTable(p_sTblName)
        self.model.select()

    def getModelRowCount(self):
        return self.model.rowCount()

    def insertRow(self):
        self.model.insertRow(self.modelRowCount)
        self.modelRowCount += 1


    def getMaxId(self):
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery("Select Max(personid) as maxid from person", self.connection)
        if (query.next()):
            return query.value(0)

        return

    def deleteRowByIndex(self, p_intIndex):
        self.model.removeRow(p_intIndex)
        self.model.submitAll()

        self.modelRowCount = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.select()

    def getDataForId(self, p_intId):
        self.model.setFilter(" personId = {}".format(p_intId))
        self.model.select()
```

and this is my controller:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql
import View
import Model

FIRST, LAST, PREVIOUS, NEXT = range(4)

class Controller(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.myDlg = View.Ui_Dialog()
        self.connectButtons()

        self.dbModel = Model.DBModel("mydb", "localhost", "root", "", "person")

        # create a model that reads from "Person" table in db "MyDB"
        self.tblRowCount = self.dbModel.modelRowCount

        self.modelRowCount = self.dbModel.getModelRowCount()

        # map the dlg fields to the db fields
        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper.ManualSubmit)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.dbModel.model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.myDlg.lineEdit, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.myDlg.lineEdit_2, 1)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.myDlg.lineEdit_3, 2)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

        self.setButtonsEnabled()

    def connectButtons(self):
        self.myDlg.pbNext.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigate(NEXT))
        self.myDlg.pbPrevious.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigate(PREVIOUS))
        self.myDlg.pbLast.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigate(LAST))
        self.myDlg.pbFirst.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigate(FIRST))

        self.myDlg.pbQuit.clicked.connect(self.quit)
        self.myDlg.pbAdd.clicked.connect(self.addRecord)
        self.myDlg.pbDelete.clicked.connect(self.deleteRecord)
        self.myDlg.pbOpenId.clicked.connect(self.openId)

    def navigate(self, p_intDirection):

        intRow = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.mapper.submit()

        if p_intDirection == FIRST:
            intRow = 0
        elif p_intDirection == LAST:
            intRow = self.dbModel.modelRowCount - 1
        elif p_intDirection == NEXT:
            intRow += 1
        elif p_intDirection == PREVIOUS:
            intRow -= 1

        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(intRow)
        self.setButtonsEnabled()

    def setButtonsEnabled(self):
        intCurrentIndex = self.mapper.currentIndex()

        if self.modelRowCount == 1:
            self.myDlg.pbPrevious.setEnabled(False)
            self.myDlg.pbNext.setEnabled(False)
            self.myDlg.pbLast.setEnabled(False)
            self.myDlg.pbFirst.setEnabled(False)
        if intCurrentIndex == 0:
            self.myDlg.pbPrevious.setEnabled(False)
            self.myDlg.pbNext.setEnabled(True)
            self.myDlg.pbLast.setEnabled(True)
            self.myDlg.pbFirst.setEnabled(False)
        elif intCurrentIndex == self.modelRowCount - 1:
            self.myDlg.pbPrevious.setEnabled(True)
            self.myDlg.pbNext.setEnabled(False)
            self.myDlg.pbLast.setEnabled(False)
            self.myDlg.pbFirst.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.myDlg.pbPrevious.setEnabled(True)
            self.myDlg.pbNext.setEnabled(True)
            self.myDlg.pbLast.setEnabled(True)
            self.myDlg.pbFirst.setEnabled(True)

    def quit(self):
        self.mapper.submit()
        QtWidgets.QDialog.accept(self.myDlg)

    def addRecord(self):
        self.mapper.submit()
        self.dbModel.insertRow()
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(self.modelRowCount + 1)

        self.modelRowCount += 1
        self.myDlg.lineEdit.setText(str(self.modelRowCount + 1))
        self.myDlg.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.myDlg.lineEdit_3.setText("")
        self.setButtonsEnabled()

        self.myDlg.lineEdit_2.setFocus()

        self.dbModel.getMaxId()

    def deleteRecord(self):
        intCrntRow = self.mapper.currentIndex()

        if QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, "Confirmation", """Are you sure you want to delete             the person
            {0} {1} ?""".format(self.lineEdit_2.text(), self.lineEdit_3.text())) == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No:
           return

        self.dbModel.deleteRowByIndex(intCrntRow)

        if intCrntRow - 1 < 0:
            intCrntRow += 1
        else:
            intCrntRow -= 1

        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(intCrntRow)

        self.setButtonsEnabled()

    def openId(self):
        self.dbModel.getDataForId(7)
        self.mapper.toFirst()
```

The point is that I read that the view should have an instance of the controller which does not here, and I don't see the point of doing it here. Especially that I don't want to change the generated file from the pyuic command.

I am not specific about what pattern to use, I was searching trying to find the most popular pattern that can be applied on desktop application with databse, using the PyQt toolkit.

Hope you can insight me in this topic.

Comment: I edited my question, I have put an example I tried to apply the MVC framework. But I don't think that I achieved to apply it correctly.

Comment: Great, it should be opened by the moderators now

Comment: If you need to modify manually the view created with the designer you can subclass it. It is a recommended best practice so that you can keep on modifying your view in the designer later on.

Comment: Thank you @Plouff for your reply. But still, I can change my view in the designer without subclassing it, if you have seen my code above, I take an instance of the view in the controller class. Unless there are more advantages of subclassing the view?

Comment: Since you said that you wanted to reference the controller in the view, I just wanted to tell you that you can do it easily if you subclass the view generated by the designer. The idea is that if you need to modify this qtdesigner view you shouldn't modify the files created with pyuic5. This not a recommended best practice since you will loose your modification when update generating a new view after an update in qtdesigner.